# How to restrict the user to select the tab in ajax tab container?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used ajax tab container in my application In that container 4 tabs available.
I need to restrict the users to select the tabs. How can i perform this operation in asp.net application.

I have tried enable=false then user unable to enter the text in the tab body.
can any one help me.

Html:

```
<ajax:TabContainer ID="tabcontainer" CssClass="Tab" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"  EnablePartialRendering="true">
    <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Basic Details" ID="tabpanelBasicDetails" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgBasicDetailsBlack" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/basicdetails-b.PNG" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button Id="btn1" runat="server"></asp:Button>
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </ajax:TabPanel>
</ajax:TabContainer>
```

Comment: Some sample code and HTML would be helpfull.

Comment: added the html code @Dean.DePue

Answer (score 0):

You can review the available Tab API in this article: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/tabs-control.ashx

There is a OnClientClick event which expects a name of a javascript function to attach to the client-side click event of the tab. You can implement your own logic that checks for the tab press and cancel the event by setting "return false" to disable the operation.

Rumen